# Does InfluxDB run on Windows

Tags: windows, jmeter, influxdb

I want to install InfluxDB on Windows for Jmeter. Can any one guide me how it can be done. Because I cannot find any specific link to get a Windows version of InfluxDB. Is Windows supported by InfluxDB ?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, InfluxDB runs fine on windows as well.

You can get the windows installable [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/influxdb/influxdb_0.9.4.2_amd64.msi).

**Additional Info:**

If you are unable to locate the config file, You can make influxdb display the default config.

For ex: `influxd.exe config`

This command displays all the default values. So create a config file with default values and modify as you need.

Then restart influxdb with below command to make the changes effective.

```
influxd.exe -config /path/to/config/file
```

Comment: Where is this download ? Is it on its official web site ? Because I could not find one.

Comment: I have downloaded it from your link and trying to run. But is it for 64 bit machine ? Because I have a 32 bit machine

Comment: As with many database systems, they only publish 64bit builds except for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and look at the [influxDB docker file](https://github.com/tutumcloud/influxdb/). You can easy run influxDB on your localhost

Comment: Not helpful here I think as he is on a 32bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 32bit version, you will need to compile it yourself. This is certainly possible but you will also need golang.

I've not done it myself so I can't be sure of the exact instructions. However there are instructions from the middle of 2015 here: http://mickesommar.com/post/Compile_influxdb_for_windows/

Also the InfluxDB github source contains some example 32bit Docker files (though not for Windows).